# What is it called when a range of two opposites is used to describe everything? (both great and small, both good and evil, both body and soul, etc.)

Tags: single-word-requests, literature

What is the literary term for a construction that coordinates two opposites or complementary ideas to describe a whole and everything in between? Both great and small, both good and evil, both body and soul, etc. It's close to *hendiadys*, but not quite.

Comment: Do you have examples, showing how it is used. There might be multiple types of this, or different reasons.

Answer (score 2):

***Merism*** or

> *synecdoche* in which totality is expressed by contrasting parts.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merism))

Answer (score 0):

These pairs are known as **(irreversible) binomials** (see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreversible_binomial)).

In English, there are certain pairs of words that often go together, connected by "and" or "or." These include "great and small," "right and wrong," "apples and oranges," and life or death."

These are called *irreversible* because the two rarely occur in the opposite order; you would be much less likely to say "small and great," "wrong and right," "oranges and apples," or "death or life."

Comment: The order of frozen pairs like those is determined by a number of things. [Cooper and Ross's "World Order"](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/worldorder.pdf) goes into the details.